# Should I continue developing my site or move on to something else?

Tags: content-management-system

So for the past year or so I've been putting a lot of time into jungleemporium.com  for a friend of mine.  It has a shopping cart that I (almost) built from scratch so I've been using it as an opportunity to learn PHP/SQL.

I kind of feel like I've come to a point where no matter what, I'm going to always feel like there's more to do.  I like having the projects to do but I don't necessarily want to re-invent the wheel.

So I think I should move on and learn something like Joomla but I still like how lean my FTP folder is compared to some bloated CMS and how I know this particular code in/out.

So what's the best thing to do?  Keep building from the ground up or jump on a major CMS bandwagon.  If so which?  Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like it is good to practice and better understand coding by building something from scratch before going to a major CMS.

But if you feel like you are tired of making everything yourself then I would suggest Joomla, since it has much more possibilities on customizing and improving than Wordpress.

Comment: I think that's the way I was leaning.  Thanks for the validation!